# How to to write a function that returns days of the week

Tags: javascript, object, return

```js
let days = {
  1: 'Monday',
  2: 'Tuesday',
  3: 'Wednesday',
  4: 'Thursday',
  5: 'Friday',
  6: 'Saturday',
  7: 'Sunday'
};

function retunDay(params) {
  if (params < 1 || params > 7) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Have you made any attempt? This seems to be a very straight forward problem. Hint look at [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the corrected version of your code ( you can also go with @vlad katz 's version if you are looking for something shorter ) but this one is just made by extending your code

```js
let days = {
    1: 'Monday',
    2: 'Tuesday',
    3: 'Wednesday',
    4: 'Thursday',
    5: 'Friday',
    6: 'Saturday',
    7: 'Sunday'
}

function retunDay(params) {
    if (params < 1 || params > 7) {
        return null;
    }
    return days[params];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let days = {
  1: 'Monday',
  2: 'Tuesday',
  3: 'Wednesday',
  4: 'Thursday',
  5: 'Friday',
  6: 'Saturday',
  7: 'Sunday'
};

function returnDay(params) {
  return params < 1 || params > 7 ? null : days[params];
}

console.log(returnDay(3));
```